# filter MAX value rows for each entry

Tags: sql

please if I want to get a MAX(changeNo) row for each "number" entry (when note is a JOIN column from another table), like query:

```
SELECT T0.id, T0.number, T0.date, T0.changeNo, T1.note 
FROM 
    table T0 INNER JOIN table2 T1 ON T0.joinID = T1.joinID 
WHERE
    changeNo = (SELECT max(changeNo) FROM table)
```

but this takes the max from the "global max", not from the max for each same "number" entry.

```
input data:
id|number|date|changeNo|note
01|150052|1603|00000001|0x22
02|150052|1603|00000002|0x45
03|150052|1603|00000003|0x64
04|150053|1603|00000001|0x89
05|150053|1603|00000002|0x56
06|150054|1603|00000001|0x77
07|150054|1603|00000002|0x84
08|150055|1603|00000001|0x46


expected output:
id|number|date|changeNo|note
03|150052|1603|00000003|0x64
05|150053|1603|00000002|0x56
07|150054|1603|00000002|0x84
08|150055|1603|00000001|0x46]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a *correlated* subquery:

```
SELECT T0.id, T0.number, T0.date, T0.changeNo, T1.note 
FROM table T0 INNER JOIN
     table2 T1
     ON T0.joinID = T1.joinID 
WHERE t0.changeNo = (SELECT max(t0.changeNo) FROM table tt0 WHERE tt0.joinID = t0.joinID) ;
```

This returns the maximum for each `joinID`.  Note:  There are other ways to implement such a query.  Often the correlated subquery is the fastest method with the right indexes, particularly one on `table(joinID, changeNo)`.